# Check for intersection between many missles and enemy?

Tags: java, multithreading, collision-detection

I want to create a class lets say called enemy 1, enemy 2, and enemy 3.

Enemy 1: Very easy to kill, but many.
Enemy 2: Harder to kill, but less of them.
Enemy 3: Boss, super hard to kill, only one.

Lets say that many is going to be 1,000. Less of them will be 100. Boss is of course one.

So it would be stupid to make 1,101 different instances for a game of just enemy. It would require to much code.

Now my fighter, which is sick, can fire a lot of missiles. Lets say 2,000 a minute for the sake of fun.

I need to check for collisions between the enemy and all the missiles. I plan only using 4 different instances. Which would be enemy1, enemy2, enemy3, and a missile.

Any ideas on how to go about this? Obviously I would need threads, but I am not sure how to check for collisions in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So it would be stupid to make 1,101 different instances for a game of just enemy. It would require to much code.

Not at all.  You may be confusing class with instance because you will in fact have to create 1,101 instances of these objects, but will only need code for 3 Enemy classes (or 1 class perhaps if you can make how hard it is to kill a property of the class).  Likely you will have a collection, such as an ArrayList of Enemy.

The other answer handles collisions, but likely you will do this part in your model, not in your view code.

Comment: Is there an example of using an array list with enemy or something that you know of?

Comment: You may be asking for too specific an example. I would look more for tutorials on using ArrayLists in general including iterating through them with for and foreach loops.

Comment: I am looking for a specific example, no matter. I think if you put their positions in an array and just check those it should work right?

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much java 101. The example will probably about creating a list of Customers or Employees or something equally boring and enterprisey. Stick with it. Think of Customers as Enemies and Employees as Boss Enemies... Quick web search: http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/Java-Arrays.cfm

Answer (score 3):

If you've got 1101 enemies wandering around the place then each of them will have their location, their damage, their ammo stock and so on, so you will need 1101 instances. You only need four *classes*. Then you create a whole array of instances of each class.

You also need an instance for every missile.

Collisions? Well, are you planning on using some 3d graphics gaming library for this? It'll probably handle collision detection. Or are your enemies all spheres? You need geometry...

Comment: Is there an exapmle of using an array list with enemy or something that you know of?

Comment: I think the OP marked the wrong answer as the solution.  This answer was the more complete one.